# NUnit/Mono not printing stack trace line number even with --debug

Tags: c#, mono, nunit, nunit-console

Ok, here's the thing, using Xamarin on OS X

(the .cs file is a very simple test case that causes a backtrace)

Compiling

```
mcs /debug /lib:~(...)NUnit-2.6.3/bin/framework/:~(...)NUnit-2.6.3/bin/lib/ -r:nunit.framework.dll test.cs
```

Running

```
mono --debug /Users/thiago/qm/nunit/NUnit-2.6.3/bin/nunit-console.exe test.exe
```

The result

```
1) Test Error : TestOne.testFirst
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at TestOne.testFirst () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke    (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr,     System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

If I use the provided nunit-console from Xamarin it works however, it does not work with several libs, etc, (for example: Monitor and some other ones)

Running only `mono test.cs` (causing a stacktrace) shows the corresponding line numbers.

Comment: Ok, so if `-framework=3.5` is added it works.

Comment: -runtime=v4.0 should be added to the mono command line

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Even this information does not help for me, any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What solved the issue for me was the option

```
-runtime=v4.0
```

(or the corresponding one to your case)

Answer (score 1):

Try passing "-config=Debug" parameter to the nunit-console like this:

```
mono --debug /Users/thiago/qm/nunit/NUnit-2.6.3/bin/nunit-console.exe test.exe -config=Debug
```

Comment: Same thing, still nothing

Comment: Do you have all .mdb files present in the working directory along with test.exe binary?

Comment: Yes, the .mdbs are there

Comment: I can confirm I am experiencing exactly the same issue. I've spent two hours trying everything possible to get it working but nothing helped. I suggest you to discuss this problem in the [nunit-discuss](http://groups.google.com/group/nunit-discuss) mailing list where you should get more answers.